# Conversion of buffer data to blob in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file

I get Buffer Data from a storage like `<Buffer 48 65 79 20 74 68 65 72 65 21>` for instance. I needed to convert it into a blob. But when i tried doing a toString() to get encoded text just like how a browser would render an attachment , i get all texts as unicode characters. I am in need of a blob I can send to UI along with other params in JSON , which could be used for view using HTML5 FileReader API. Could you please favour.

What i tried was below, where buffer refers to the data as in first line.

```
let binBuffer = Buffer.from(buffer,'binary').toString('utf8');
```

Comment: let binBuffer = new Blob([buffer]);

Comment: what does buffer denote? @ScottStensland like one in line 1 of question or as array say data:[48,65,79..] which we get on JSON.stringify(bufferdata) ?

Comment: You should really consider *not* sending binary data with your JSON.  The only way to do that is base64 encoding, which adds 33% overhead in size, a lot of extra CPU and memory.  Not to mention, on the receiving end you need several copies in memory as you go through the decoding steps.  It's best if you have a separate HTTP request for the binary data.  If for some reason this isn't possible, consider a binary format like CBOR rather than JSON.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### If you're here to convert a Node.js `Buffer` to a [JavaScript `Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob):

First of all, Node.js didn't have the `Blob` class until versions [`v15.7.0` and `v14.18.0`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/buffer.html#class-blob), so you need to import the `Blob` class if you haven't already:

```js
// NOTE: starting from Node.js v18.0.0, the following code is not necessary anymore

// CJS style
const { Blob } = require("buffer");

// ESM style
import { Blob } from "buffer";
```

> NOTE: it appears that in Node.js v14/v15/v16/v17 (last checked: as of `v14.19.2`, `v15.14.0`, `v16.14.2` and `v17.9.0`), the `Blob` class is marked as experimental and not stable. Instead, in Node.js `v18.x.x` the `Blob` class is marked as stable.

> UPDATE 2022-04-25: starting with [Node.js version `18.0.0`](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/), you don't have to manually import the `Blob` class anymore, but you can use it straight away in your code!

Once the `Blob` class is available, the conversion itself is pretty simple:

```js
const buff = Buffer.from([1, 2, 3]); // Node.js Buffer
const blob = new Blob([buff]); // JavaScript Blob
```

### Old answer about how to transfer a Node.js `Buffer` via JSON:

If you need to transfer a buffer of data through JSON, you can encode the buffer using a text-based encoding like hexadecimal or base64.

For instance:

```js
// get the buffer from somewhere
const buff = fs.readFileSync("./test.bin");
// create a JSON string that contains the data in the property "blob"
const json = JSON.stringify({ blob: buff.toString("base64") });

// on another computer:
// retrieve the JSON string somehow
const json = getJsonString();
const parsed = JSON.parse(json);
// retrieve the original buffer of data
const buff = Buffer.from(parsed.blob, "base64");
```

Comment: This snippet is very useful, thanks, but people will be getting here for a Buffer->Blob conversion, maybe we could also add some mention to `const blob = new Blob([buffer])`?

Answer (score -2):

Here's an updated example using SDK v3:

## Encrypt

```js
const { KMSClient, EncryptCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-kms");

const mySecret = 'Something really important goes here';
const client = new KMSClient({region: 'my-region-here'});
const encryptCommand= new EncryptCommand({KeyId: 'my-kms-key-id', Plaintext: Buffer.from(mySecret) });
const encryptionResult = await client.send(encryptCommand);
const cipherText = Buffer.from(encryptionResult.CiphertextBlob).toString('base64')
console.log(cipherText);
```

## Decrypt

```js
const { KMSClient, DecryptCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-kms");

const cipherText = 'base64 string from above or another encrypt command';
const client = new KMSClient({region: 'my-region-here'});
const decryptCommand= new DecryptCommand({KeyId: 'my-kms-key-id', CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(cipherText, 'base64') });
const decryptionResult = await client.send(decryptCommand);
const originalSecret = Buffer.from(decryptionResult.Plaintext).toString();
console.log(originalSecret);
```